# C# regex problem

Tags: c#, regex

```
"<div class=\"standings-rank\">([0-9]{1,2})</div>"
```

Here's my regex. I want to Match it but C# returns me something like

```
"<div class=\"standings-rank\">1</div>"
```

When I'd like to just get

```
"1"
```

How can I make C# return me the right thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Match.Groups[int]` indexer.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<div class=\"standings-rank\">([0-9]{1,2})</div>");
string str = "<div class=\"standings-rank\">1</div>";
string value = regex.Match(str).Groups[1].Value;

Console.WriteLine(value); // Writes "1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a Regex declared as follows:

```
 Regex pattern = new Regex("<div class=\"standings-rank\">([0-9]{1,2})</div>");
```

and are testing said regex via the `Match` method; then you must access the match starting at index 1 not index 0;

```
 pattern.Match("<div class=\"standings-rank\">1</div>").Groups[1].Value
```

This will return the expected value; index 0 will return the whole matched string.

Specifically, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.groupcollection.aspx)

> The collection contains one or more
>   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group
>   objects. If the match is successful,
>   the first element in the collection
>   contains the Group object that
>   corresponds to the entire match. Each
>   subsequent element represents a
>   captured group, if the regular
>   expression includes capturing groups.
>   If the match is unsuccessful, the
>   collection contains a single
>   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group
>   object whose Success property is false
>   and whose Value property equals
>   String.Empty.